# How would I use a file as the iostream in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

The user puts 
./prog file1.txt < file2.txt
How would I make it so that file2.txt is seen as the iosteam?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but `std::cout` in prog will be written to file2.txt given that command line.

Comment: If I'm not on crack, you have the wrong `>`. For input you want `<`

Comment: yeah it should be < @user4581301 I made a typo whoops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to doing it that way. The `>` tells the shell to open `file2.txt` for writing. The same stream is  then connected to your program's `stdout`/`std::cout` so that whatever you print will be put in that file. So you don't have an `iostream` but `std::cout` is connected to that file.

You need to give the file as an argument to your program if you want full control, just as you give `file1.txt` as an argument to the program:

```
./prog file1.txt file2.txt
```

You can now open both files inside `prog`.

Comment: Ah I was a bit confused. I thought that < was another way to input a file. I figured out what I need to do. Thank you.